# Pass Property of Class to ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, validationattribute

I am trying to write my own `ValidationAttribute` for which I want to pass the value of a parameter of my class to the `ValidationAttribute`. Very simple, if the boolean property is `true`, the property with the `ValidationAttribute` on top should not be null or empty.

My class:

```
public class Test
{
    public bool Damage { get; set; }
    [CheckForNullOrEmpty(Damage)]
    public string DamageText { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My Attribute:

```
public class CheckForNullOrEmpty: ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly bool _damage;

    public RequiredForWanrnleuchte(bool damage)
    {
        _damage = damage;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string damageText = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance).ToString();
        if (_damage == true && string.IsNullOrEmpty(damageText))
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

However, I cannot simply pass the property inside the class to the ValidationAttribute like that. What would be a solution to pass the value of that property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of passing the `bool` value to the `CheckForNullOrEmptyAttribute`, you should pass the name of the corresponding property; within the attribute, you then can retrieve this `bool` value from the object instance being validated.

The `CheckForNullOrEmptyAttribute` below, can be applied on your model as shown here.

```
public class Test
{
    public bool Damage { get; set; }

    [CheckForNullOrEmpty(nameof(Damage))] // Pass the name of the property.
    public string DamageText { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class CheckForNullOrEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public CheckForNullOrEmptyAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var hasValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);
        if (hasValue)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        // Retrieve the boolean value.  
        var isRequired =
            Convert.ToBoolean(
                validationContext.ObjectInstance
                    .GetType()
                    .GetProperty(PropertyName)
                    .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance)
                );
        if (isRequired)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```